# "Git Log" command in Powershell - unable to terminate process

Tags: git, powershell, logging, terminal, command

When I type `git log` in PowerShell it prints what looks like a normal response.

But at the bottom it doesn't show the normal working directory that prompts me for a new command, it just shows `:` (a colon) and no command works; not quit, not <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>z</kbd>, not <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd>, it just prints another colon.

Comment: try `j`,`k`, or `h` for help and `q` for quit. :)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It puts you in a pager (most probably `less` if you installed MSysGit or Github for Windows), because the output you requested is longer than one screen page.

You can scroll up/down/left/right with your arrow keys, the <kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd> keys and the <kbd>J</kbd>/<kbd>K</kbd>/<kbd>H</kbd>/<kbd>L</kbd> keys.

To show inline help, press <kbd>?</kbd> and to quit, press <kbd>Q</kbd>.

You can use a different pager or turn it off if you want to. As [`man git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) points out, you can use the `core.pager` setting to set it to a different pager, or set its value to `cat` to disable pagination for all Git commands.

Answer (score 23):

If the pager is killed using <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> then the pager keeps running in the background and on each newline in terminal it will print a line and `(END)`. So far I have not found a way of saving such a terminal. When I `exit` the terminal, the pager still keeps it alive until I kill the window.

<kbd>q</kbd> works to exit the pager / `less`-command if <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> has not been used.

Comment: This is the info I needed! I've always tried Ctrl-C first and then get stuck in the pager. It was driving me bananas that Q wasn't working.

Answer (score 13):

You just need type <kbd>q</kbd> to exit the screen!